# Where can I find build in sounds in fcpx

Tags: audio, final-cut-pro-x

I a editing a video and I want to add some sound effects ie by some places add some small Bits of audio. Is there built in audio files in fcpx like in iMovie? Or do I need a plug-in? And if that is the case, what plugin?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you do “Download Additional Content” under the Final Cut Pro menu. Download and install if you haven’t.

Left top corner next to the Library Sidebar icon is the Photo and Audio Sidebar Icon. When you in this sidebar you can find “Sound Effects” with lots of sounds you can use for free.

Comment: Doesn’t that reform the sound of people speeding? If yes, I don’t mean that. I mean sound like a peep or something longer or else

Comment: You can search in it and always alternate what is in there to fit your needs.

Comment: how can I search?

Comment: I want to have some sound by a specific part of the video, but fcpx only allows me to put the sound effect by the whole video

Comment: You can search on the top of the sound effects column.

Comment: You can cut or trim the end of sound effect to the length you need.

Comment: I cant add the sound effect as standalone sound as I want....

Comment: Did you try to add it below the main timeline?

Comment: it only shows the plus when I hover over a video....

Comment: You should be able to use drag and drop for most operations.

Comment: I  know, but it doesnt work...

Comment: Not sure how to help further without a screenshot of your timeline.

Comment: Maybe this might help https://youtu.be/6vHwk2ocHy0

Comment: ok, will check it out
thx a lot!!